# How to change texture via a button press in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D model of a sofa whose texture I want to change via a texture change button displayed on screen.

eg. if I touch the red button, the sofa color will be red; if I touch the black button, the sofa color will be black.

Currently, I can change the sofa texture by touching anywhere on screen but now I want to touch a particular button and have the sofa texture change according to the button.

Here is my what I have so far:

```
public class change_texture : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture[] texture;
    public int currentTexture;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            currentTexture++;
            currentTexture %= texture.Length;
            GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = texture [currentTexture];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the GUI button OnClick event. Firstly Change your script (attached to sofa) to this one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class textureChange : MonoBehaviour {

     public Texture[] texture; //set in inspector
     public int[] price; // price for every texture (in parallel to the textures array)
     public int currentTexture; //set default/starting index in inspector
     bool shouldChange = false; //this bool is set to prevent unwanted texture changes to the same texture every frame
     public Text priceObject; // the Price text object
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape; //your code
        priceObject.text = "Price: " + price[currentTexture] + "$";  //show default price
    }
    public void changetexture(int textureToSet)
    {
        currentTexture = textureToSet;
        shouldChange = true;
    }
    public void incrementtexture()
    {
        currentTexture++;
        shouldChange = true;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (shouldChange)
        {
            shouldChange = false; 
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture[currentTexture]; //set new texture
            priceObject.text = "Price: " + price[currentTexture] + "$";
        }
    }
}
```

Then Add buttons to your scene with a canvas as a parent.
In the buttons inspectors, add a function to the OnClick list by:

1. pressing the '+' button.
2. dragging sofa game object to the inspector.
3. selecting the changetexture function inside textureChange script.
4. setting the new textures index (0 is first texture,1 is second, and so on).

[image]

Comment: Why are you running that in the Update? Also no way to prevent out of bounds?

Answer (score 0):

HI WizzardMaker and itay_421 i tried your solution but unfortunately it's not working.

here i attach screen what i have done check and let me know where i m wrong.

[image]

[image]

please check and let me know as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you press the button? I do not understand if the solution worked or not. also try to debug the code.

Comment: if i pass static value in script in index it will work fine. now if i have multiple texture more than 5 and want to change one by one on same button click how can i do that?

Comment: I added the incrementtexture() method to my answer. change the OnClick function to this one.

Comment: Volla!! thanks working as expected.... now my last question how can i change price based on button i touch. right now i go with different button touch option that's why!!!.

Comment: hi itay_421 can you please look into above comment and reply.

Comment: I edited my question again. in `price[]` assign the price values in parallel to `texture[]`. MAKE SURE that `texture[]` and `price[]` have the same length. To priceObject assign a UI text game object which will display the price.